# Best practices for storing data from hundreds of fields

Tags: mysql, database

I have a form with about 500+ fields (it's a 10 page form, different data types).  Can you guys please advise me on the best way to store the data from the form?  I can create 500 fields in multiple, logically divided tables but that seems a lot (or maybe that's the best way?!) since I have a few of these forms.  I am looking into serializing the data and storing in longtext mysql field.  That will have its drawbacks (the one I am thinking of is if the customer wants to search individual fields in the future) but it does seem like a pretty fast solution. I will appreciate if you would share you experience with a similar situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumibly you dont expect the user to fill the form in in a single sitting! So you will need some sort of work flow to store drafts and amend previous copies etc.

Also assuming some parts of the form are optional.

You could either define a set of database tables with a master table to track status, user name etc, and a child table for each optional part of the form.

Or you could define an XML schema which contains all the possible fields in the form etc plus some status information.

If you always process the entire form and dont want to search through your collection  of forms then the XML soiution is slightly better as there are some nifty tricks for moving data from XML to HTML forms and back again. If you need to search based on values inside the form then the SQL based solution is preferable.

Comment: Thanks James.  I actually will have a schema of the form fields in a table (with a whole bunch of field attributes) instead of xml.  That part works really nicely.  Also, the serialized data going back and forth works pretty nicely.  I guess it would be best to ask the customer if they will need a field level search and go off of their answer (yes:make a column for each field, no: serialize)

Answer (score 2):

You may need 500 columns - unless they can be placed in other tables. It can be hard to tell without seeing your requirements.

Serialising it would make one of the advantages of using a database impossible - querying against certain column values.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table profile_details (
   user_id number,
   field_name varchar,
   field_value varchar
);
```

Now you are not only not limited by number of fields, you also pretty free to add and remove them as you keep developing and maintaining your app.

```
select firstname, lastname, zipcode 
from profiles p 
join profile_details d1 on (p.user_id=d1.user_id) 
join profile_details d2 on (p.user_id=d2.user_id) 
where d1.field_name='hobby' and d1.field_value='fishing'
and   d2.field_name='income' and d2.field_value>cast(250000 as number);
```

Comment: This solution will break down as soon as there is a repeating section in the form. Supposing the form has a section for "hobbies" you then need to store "hobby-1" "hobby-2" etc.  Also searching with meaningful search results gets really messy. How would you do "select firstname, lastname, zipcode where hobby = "Stamp Collecting" and income > 250000.

Comment: For the first of your problems, at least you can code this logic into your application, while with 500-field table you can't do anything at all. For the second part, I'm going to update my answer in a minute.

Comment: There must be an official name for this anti-pattern -- "Dynamic solution to a static problem". Whatever you do a new attribute will require layout, validation and code changes another db column is not much extra work. Plus if you are using a rails/grails type framework most of this code is for free when you add a column to your schema.

Comment: James, eventually you will realize that the biggest headache you can have is changing database schema when you system is in production and accumulated a lot of data.